# FreeLibraryAndExitThread crashes program when unloading injected DLL

Tags: c++, windows, dll, reverse-engineering, dll-injection

I am writing a DLL that gets injected into a game in order to play around with some reverse engineering. For a while I was able to successfully inject, eject and reinject as I made changes to the program. I'm using `FreeLibraryAndExitThread` to unload.

After adding XInput to the program so I could catch user input, the game crashes with an access violation when I call `FreeLibraryAndExitThread`. Going from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19934000/how-to-correctly-dispose-of-injected-dll-thread/19935609#19935609), I'm guessing that using XInput is leaving something *'live'* in the program when I go to unload, and that's what's causing the crash. I'm honestly at a loss as to how to fix this.

Here's the code that's crashing the program on exit:

```
    XINPUT_STATE state;
    ZeroMemory(&state, sizeof(XINPUT_STATE));

    //The problematic line of code
    bool gamepad = XInputGetState(0, &state) == ERROR_SUCCESS; 

    WORD buttonsHeld = state.Gamepad.wButtons;
    WORD buttonsPressed = (~previousButtonState) & state.Gamepad.wButtons;
    WORD buttonsReleased = previousButtonState & (~state.Gamepad.wButtons);
```

When I remove the call to `XInputGetState`, everything works just fine and I'm able to unload the DLL without crashing.

And here's how I'm calling for the program to unload and exit

```
    FreeLibraryAndExitThread(hDLL, 0);
```

Where `hDLL` is the argument `hinstDLL` from `DllMain`. I've also tried `GetModuleHandleEx` instead of using `hinstDLL`.

My guess is either:

- Using `XInputGetState` makes my program load a second DLL for `XInput`, or
- `XInputGetState` is creating some sort of reference to my DLL when called and when I remove my DLL, it's trying to access memory that's no longer there.

EDIT: I did a bit of digging and the problem seems to be that adding the call to `XInputGetState` causes my DLL to load `XINPUT1_4.dll`. I tried using `FreeLibrary` to unload it but that isn't working.

EDIT: I narrowed it down some more - it turns out that the access violation is being caused by some thread within the game trying to return to part of XINPUT1_4.dll's code, which is unloaded, making it crash. And I have no clue how to fix that.

Final Edit: It was a simple fix, I had to call `LoadLibrary(L"XINPUT1_4.dll")` for the DLL that was causing the issue.

Comment: If the game is already using XInput for its own purposes then it should have its own open reference to `xinput1_4.dll`, thus loading and freeing your own reference should not be unloading that DLL from memory as its reference count would not fall to 0.

Comment: Try loading `xinput1_4.dll` explicitly in your DLL (LoadLibrary, GetProcAddress) rather than linking to it statically.  If you leave it loaded when your DLL unloads, there might not be a problem.

Comment: The game actually loads an older version of XInput, it loads version 1.3. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Actually, that worked! DllMain creates a thread, that thread calls `LoadLibrary("XINPUT1_4.dll");` and it's working when I unload!

Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's the solution:

The problem was that invoking `XInputGetState` caused my DLL to automatically load `XINPUT1_4.dll`, and when I called FreeLibraryAndExitThread, my DLL unloading forced the XInput DLL to unload as well. Code within the program (probably from a thread in XInput 1.4) attempted to execute code that was no longer there, causing an access violation.

So the solution was simply to call `LoadLibrary(L'XINPUT1_4.dll')` after I initialize my DLL's thread so that when my DLL is unloaded, the XInput DLL stays in memory because the `LoadLibrary` increases the reference count.

(When a DLL's reference count reaches 0, it unloads. It is initialized as 1 when you first load it, LoadLibrary increments it by 1, and calling FreeLibraryAndExitThread decrements it by 1. So when all is said and done, its reference count is above 0 and it remains in memory as my DLL is unloaded)